# Use generate_series to create a table

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift, generate-series

In Amazon Redshift, `generate_series()` seems to be supported on the leader node, but not on the compute nodes.  Is there a way to use generate_series to create a table on the leader node, and then push it to the compute nodes?

This query runs fine, running on the leader node:

```
with
    date_table as (select now()::date - generate_series(0, 7 * 10) as date),
    hour_table as (select generate_series(0, 24) as hour),
    time_table as (
      select 
        date_table.date::date as date,
        extract(year from date_table.date) as year,
        extract(month from date_table.date) as month,
        extract(day from date_table.date) as day,
        hour_table.hour
    from date_table CROSS JOIN hour_table
)
SELECT * 
from time_table
```

However, this query fails:

```
create table test
diststyle all
as (
  with
      date_table as (select now()::date - generate_series(0, 7 * 10) as date),
      hour_table as (select generate_series(0, 24) as hour),
      time_table as (
        select 
          date_table.date::date as date,
          extract(year from date_table.date) as year,
          extract(month from date_table.date) as month,
          extract(day from date_table.date) as day,
          hour_table.hour
    from date_table CROSS JOIN hour_table
)
  SELECT * 
  from time_table 
);
```

The only solution I can think of right now is to pull the query results into another program (e.g. python) and then insert the result into the database, but that seems hackish.

For those of you who've never used redshift, it's a heavily modified variant of postgresql, and has lots of it's own idiosyncrasies.  The below query is completely valid an runs fine:

```
create table test diststyle all as (select 1 as a, 2 as b);
select * from test
```

yields:

```
a   b
1   2
```

The problem stems from the difference between leadernode only function and compute node functions on redshift.  I'm pretty sure it's not due to a bug in my query.

Comment: `test diststyle all` is an invalid table name. Use `create table test as ...` or `create table test_diststyle_all as ...` And no `(` after the `as` in `create table .. as`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Redshift is a heavily modified variant of postgres.  When you create a table in redshfit, you may specify a distribution style (distkey, diststyle even, or distyle all) that controls how to the table is distributed across the cluster.  The above SQL is completely valid, and if I replace the as (...) with something else (e.g. `select * from users limit 1`) the query runs fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found a way to use leader-node only functions to create tables. There is not (AFAICT) any magic syntax that you can use to make them load their output back to a table.

I ended up using number tables to achieve a similar outcome. Even a huge number table will take up very little space on your Redshift cluster with runlength compression.

Comment: I think that's what I'll do too.  How big did you make the numbers table, and did you distribute it with diststyle even?

Comment: I have several number table in increasing orders of magnitude (10/100/1,000/10,000/100,000/1,000,000). They are all set to `DISTSTYLE ALL`.